# qt creator and release build (to work on different mac machines)

Tags: qt, build, qt5, qt-creator, release

I am trying to run release build on different mac os machines, I can successfully make release build but it does not work on other mac arguing on qt libraries and this is ok, because on other mac there is no qt library installed. How can I make a build which also includes all qt dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add:

```
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
```

and platforms folder which you can find in

```
QtDirectory/mscvc_2013/plugins
```

add all of this to your .exe created out of the release.